# Firebird ConnectionString Change during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, firebird

I'm working on an app that has a live network database and a contingency local database, and it detects whether the live network db is accessible, and, if not, it times out after three seconds, changing the connectionstring to the local contingency database.

Following tips here on SO, I managed to alter the connectionstring on app.config during run time *and* reload the settings.

This is the method the app calls when a change on the connection string is needed:

```
    public static void ChangeConnectionString(string connectionstring)
    {
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
    connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString = connectionstring;
    var connectionStrings = config.ConnectionStrings;
    foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connectionString in connectionStrings.ConnectionStrings)
    {
            connectionString.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
    }
    config.Save();
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    PDV_WPF.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    PDV_WPF.Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    //Ensures the configuration is saved and reloaded.
    FbConnection.ClearAllPools();
    //Closes all currently open connections which might be using the old connection string.
    Debug.WriteLine("==========Ran ChangeConnectionString");
    Debug.WriteLine("==========FDBConnString is:");
    Debug.WriteLine("==========" + PDV_WPF.Properties.Settings.Default.FDBConnString);
```

After I disconnect my computer form the network, whenever I check the current FDBConnString, it correctly points to the local contingency database. However, on the very next line, when it tries to run a query, I get the following exception:

```
Inner Exception 1:
IscException: Unable to complete network request to host "dbserver".

Inner Exception 2:
SocketException: Este host não é conhecido //(This host is unknown)
```

Full exception details: https://pastebin.com/3syLvsQf

It seems that, even after I successfully change the connection string, and successfully reload the application config file, it still tries to open a connection using the old connection string. Even if I call Debug to print the current Properties.Settings.Default.FDBConnString right on the line above the call for FbConnection.Open(), it shows the *new string* rather than the incorrect, old one.

Any insights on what might be going on?

Comment: What version of the Firebird ado.net provider are you using?

Comment: I've grabbed the NuGet package, version 5.11.0, and I had to use that workaround involving accessing the privateregistry.bin for the provider to show on the list of registered providers on Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the issue.
I am instancing a inherited table adapter from the generated xsd file. When I declare a table adapter on my class it also inherits the connection string stored on app.config at the time of declaration. So it doesn't matter if I change app.config, as the declared table adapter is already stuck with the previous connection string.

So, the solution was, rather than changing the connection string stored on app.config, I just had to change the connection string on the declared table adapter:

```
tB_STOCKTableAdapter1.Connection.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.ContingencyDB;
tB_STK_PRODUCTTableAdapter1.Connection.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.ContingencyDB;
```

or

```
tB_STOCKTableAdapter1.Connection.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.NetworkDB;
tB_STK_PRODUCTTableAdapter1.Connection.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.NetworkDB;
```

Both ContingencyDB and NetworkDB are strings stored on app.config as a user-scoped string, which can be changed via a given "Settings" window presented to the user.